# Twig Access Array Index?

Tags: twig, silex

Is it possible to directly access an array index from within a Twig template?

Here's my setup, using Silex:

```
return $app['twig']->render('template', array('numbers' => array('one', 'two', 'three')));
```

so can I do something like this?

```
{{numbers[0]}}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Just before posting this I realized, that's exactly what you can do, but as I didn't find the answer anywhere in the docs or google (correct me if I'm wrong), I've posted this anyway.

```
{{numbers[0]}}
```

Comment: It does mention subscript access here under section "Variables" http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html

Comment: @gunnx So it does, I missed it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Adam, is correct, only to make it clear and improve,
you can have access directly to array index

```
{{ myArray[0] }}
```

if you need to access in a loop

```
{% set arrayOfItems = ['ZERO', 'ONE'] %}
{% set myArray = ['APPLE', 'ORANGE'] %}
{% for oneItem in arrayOfItems %}
    <p>{{ oneItem }} equals {{ myArray[loop.index0] }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

in this example I used an array inside a non related loop so the result is:

```
ZERO equals APPLE
ONE equals ORANGE
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats actually something what doesnt work for me when using Twig with shopware 6.
I try to access an object like

```
{{ page.cart.lineItems.elements[0].quantity }}
```

what will lead into a parsing error of the Twig Template

I can use

```
{{ page.cart.lineItems.elements | first }}
```

to get the first Element, but dont know how i can then access a property of this first element

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30119811)

Answer (score 0):

The Answer from [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11843882/22715046) is still correct and also works in Multidimensional Arrays. Just the comment with the Documentation Link is inccorect, which you find [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html) as of 2024

```
{{numbers[x][y]}}
```