# Assistance with reading values in nested array

Tags: arrays, twig

I am working on a twig form view.  I am feeding the view a nested array of elements that will be used to prepopulate the form inputs.  I know the array exists on the view since I can show it by using `{{ }}` or `{% %}` type statements.

I loop through the array and start creating form elements, but I'm having trouble accessing the key/value pair in the array while in the loop.

Here is my code:

```html
{% for key, value in csvRowData %}
    <tr class='inforow' id='{{formRowId}}'>
        {% for slKey,slValue in startList %}
            {% set inputName = slValue.name %}
            {% set gman1 = slValue.name %}
            {% set inputVal = value.gman1 %}

            <td class="{{slValue.td_class}} ">
                {{inputName}}
                {{inputVal}}

                <div class="form-group">
                {% if slValue.type is same as('text') %}
                    <input type='text' value="{{value.ward}}" data-type="{{slValue.name}}" name="0[{{slValue.name}}]" class="{{slValue.inpt_class}}" placeholder=". {{slValue.placeholder}}">
                {% endif %}
                </div>
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the csvRowData array so you can see it's structure etc:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ward] => AWARD
        [mrn] => 123456
        [client_name] => gman donster
        [bill_number] => bill1
        [salesforce_id] => sf1
        [michart_results] => on
        [dd_test] => Han
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ward] => BWARD
        [mrn] => 789012
        [client_name] => logan thunder
        [bill_number] => bill2
        [salesforce_id] => sf2
        [michart_results] => Greedo
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [ward] => CWARD
        [mrn] => 345678
        [client_name] => hunter landseeker
        [bill_number] => bill3
        [salesforce_id] => sf3
        [michart_results] => on
        [dd_test] => Chewie
    )

)
```

within the main loop, I also do an inner loop on another array fed to the view called '`startList`'; this one I am not having any problems with as I access items within its loop without any problem.

I think what is going on is this.

1. If I try to show `{{csvRowData.0.ward}}` it will show me that value which is 'AWARD'
2. The problem comes in where I am setting a var to be the key that I am trying to access
3. Then twig does not seem to be able to interpret it...
4. Using the example from #1:
5. I do `{%  set gman1 = 'ward' %}`
6. I then try to access that value by doing `{{csvRowData.0.gman1}}` and it shows nothing (twig cannot find it or interpret it)

So that is the question, does anyone know why #1 works fine and (5 and 6) do not work at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twig - Dynamic array key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40975260/twig-dynamic-array-key)

Comment: You shouldn't add tags to the title...

Answer (score 0):

well i tried googling again but a different question and found an answer; here is the link:  [Twig Access Array Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843880/twig-access-array-index)

basically need to express it as:

```html
csvRowData.0[gman1]
```